# Tool to execute shell script

Tags: linux, windows, shell

I have a requirement to execute multiple shell scripts on the Linux severs regularly. Is there any tool in windows that connect to a Linux server and execute the given script with given user and shows the output in windows machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use plink (http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html), you also can use putty to execute the ssh command but you can't get the output.

```
C:\>plink.exe -ssh root@1.1.1.1 -pw mypassword uptime
06:40:58 up 50 days,  3:30,  8 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.07, 0.10

C:\>plink.exe -ssh root@1.1.1.1 -pw mypassword uptime > output.txt

C:\>type output.txt
06:41:45 up 50 days,  3:31,  8 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.06, 0.09
```

execute script

```
C:\>type cmd.txt
uptime

C:\>plink.exe -ssh root@1.1.1.1 -pw mypassword -m cmd.txt
06:41:45 up 50 days,  3:31,  8 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.06, 0.09
```

Comment: Wonderful, I am looking for this kind of tool only.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/). Just create a saved session using SSH which executes the script on the server. It will SSH into the sever, execute the script, and display the output.

Comment: I am looking for any tool that stores username, password and path of the script and to return the output. I don't want to enter the input manually.

Comment: @user1005707 Yes, PuTTY can do that; you can set up a [saved session](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.62/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-saving) which includes a [username](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.62/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-username) and the [command to run](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.62/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-ssh). It won't save the password, but the preferred way to do this securely is use an SSH key and [Pageant](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter9.html) to load it once and then not have to type the password again.